# Azure, what does "Enable managed boot diagnostics" give you that you cant get without it?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

When you create a VM (e.g. ubuntu) with Azure, one option is "Enable managed boot diagnostics".  I have read the linked help page, but this didnt help.

Surely, if the OS has a problem starting, and ssh is not working, there is way to view the console output via azure portal?

If so, why would you want to "enable managed boot diagnostics", which presumably ads significant cost for small instances?

I was shocked that there was no option in the portal to re-image a given server in Azure (you have to delete it and recreate it, and all its resources).  Maybe they also don't give you a way to view the console output, hence requiring you to pay extra for this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't connect to the console of VM's in Azure. Using managed boot diagnostics, you can get screenshots and connect to the serial console of the VM. In a properly configured linux VM, the serial console gives you access to a login prompt.